# Spotify change:context event

Tags: javascript, spotify, spotify-app

I have the following code:

```
function initializeUI(){
    //More code here

    models.player.addEventListener('change:context', contextChanged);

    //More code here
}

var timerId = null;
function contextChanged() {
    models.player.load('context').done(function (player) {
        if (player.context.uri == tempPlaylist.uri) {
            //User started playing this context. Start timer.
            timerId = setInterval(updateTimerView, 1000);
        }
        else {
            //User is playing a different context. Delete temp playlist and timer.
            models.Playlist.removeTemporary(tempPlaylist);
            clearInterval(timerId);
        }
    });
}

function updateTimerView(){
    //UI related code goes here
}
```

I would assume that `change:context` would only be fired when the context (in my case, `tempPlaylist`) is changed, but it turns out that it's also being fired when the track is changed, played, or paused. This can't be the desired functionality... otherwise it would defeat the purpose of having the `change:track` and `change:playing` events.

This is causing a lot of trouble for me mainly because when the track is changed, played, or paused, `contextChanged` is called, but `player.context.uri` hasn't changed, so more and more timers keep getting added. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, looks like a bug.  I'd probably change it to something like this

```
require(['$api/models'], function(models) {

    models.player.addEventListener('change:context', contextChanged);

    var last_context=null;
    function contextChanged(e) {
        if(last_context != e.oldValue.uri) {
            last_context = e.oldValue.uri;
            console.log('hola, new context uri - ' + last_context);
        }
        else {
            console.log('faux context change');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this worked out pretty well. Just to note, `e.oldValue` was returning null every once and a while. After adding a check for that, everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Of course, you'd probably want to use e.target.context.uri not oldValue.uri (since it's the old value).